# NSMutableAttributedString to know where color is changed on which text

Tags: ios, nsmutableattributedstring

I am doing tagging feature like facebook and I can tag user already. I can show like this. It is done by this code.

```
NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:self.textView.text];

for (NSString *word in self.tagNameCollection) {
    [string addColor:[UIColor redColor] substring:word];
    [string addBackgroundColor:[Helpers getFromRGB:135 green:206 blue:250] substring:word];
}
```

So, I have NSMutableAttributedString. Can I know where I have changed colour, font from my NSMutableAttributedString? May I know how to do?

[image]

Comment: Lookt at `enumerateAttributesInRange:options:usingBlock:`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`enumerateAttributesInRange:options:usingBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/enumerateAttributesInRange:options:usingBlock:) to get what are the attributes of your `NSAttributedString`.

Example:

```
[attributedString enumerateAttributesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [attributedString length])
                                     options:0
                                  usingBlock:^(NSDictionary *attributes, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
if ([attributes objectForKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName])
    NSLog(@"Found ForeGround Color: %@ in range %@", [attributes objectForKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName], NSStringFromRange(range));
if ([attributes objectForKey:NSFontAttributeName])
    NSLog(@"Found Font: %@ in range %@", [attributes objectForKey:NSFontAttributeName], NSStringFromRange(range));
if ([attributes objectForKey:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName])
    NSLog(@"Found Background Color: %@ in range %@", [attributes objectForKey:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName], NSStringFromRange(range));

}];
```

Comment: Thanks. It seem okay. Do I always need to keep NSMutableAttributedString and update when something is changed in my uitextview? Can I get NSMutableAttributedString from my uitextview? If I do like this,   property of NSMutableAttributedString is gone. 
  NSMutableAttributedString *muStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:self.inputToolBarViewInDetail.textView.text];

Comment: If you want to know the changes, you may have to keep a reference from the previous one, or maybe check the `UITextViewDelegate` method when text is modified.